# React - Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gatsby

I am really at my wits end with this. I'm trying to build & deploy a Gatsby site and I am getting the above error after trying to build the static HTML pages. The CSS and JS files all build without issue.

I get a WebpackError with this as well: `WebpackError: Minified React error #130;` Which can be found here: [#130](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=130&args%5B%5D=object&args%5B%5D=)

[Gatsby's Docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/) suggest that this `#130 error` is due to mixing up `import` and `require` calls in the same file. I have been through my entire directory hunting for something like this, and I can not find anywhere where this occurs. I don't seem to have any of the other issues the Gatsby docs also suggest for this error either.

Has anyone else ran into this problem, and if so, what was the solution for you? I'm not sure how to go about posting code, because I don't even know what the problem is here. Everything compiles and runs locally without issue on the dev server, which is kind of why I am stumped. How can the code compile and work perfectly locally but not build & deploy?

Comment: You need to share the impacted code for us to help

Comment: I don't even know what code to isolate and share. The errors don't say. There are probably 25+ .js files in this project.

Comment: This may be caused by not only mixing `import` and `require`, but also by forgetting a component to export or even importing a library wrong like `import { Foo } from "foo";` instead of `import Foo from "foo";` or even a typo in import syntax! So, you need to dig your components a little bit more.

Comment: If you run `gatsby develop` and visit each of your pages you'll almost certainly run into the error and you'll isolate the problematic component.

Comment: @coreyward thank you for this. I was so frantic in trying to sort this out that I did not even consider running that command.

Answer (score 3):

This was solved. For anyone building a site with Gatsby, the issue is that I had a `/styles` directory for my styled components located in the `src/pages` directory.

This throws an error when building because Gatsby expects JS files inside of the `/src/pages` directory to only be exported React components, which in turn represent a page of the website.

I moved the styles into `/src` and voila. This caused the error because styled components are JS files, and as mentioned above, Gatsby is not expecting anything else other than exported React components inside of `/src/pages`.

Comment: This is crazy. I was digging into this for half a day! Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @Parth glad I could be of some help here. This was a keyboard banger.